# Python Co-occurrence matrix of words and phrases

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, matrix

I'm working with two text files. One contains a list of 58 words (L1), and the other one contains 1173 phrases (L2). I want to check `for i in range(len(L1))` and `for j in range(len(L1))` the co-occurrence in `L2`.

For example:

```
L1 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 't', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
L2 = ['the onion', 'be your self', 'great zoo', 'x men', 'corn day']

for i in range(len(L1)):
    for j in range(len(L1)):
        for s in range(len(L2)):
            if L1[i] in L2[s] and L1[j] in L2[s]:
                output = L1[i], L1[j], L2[s]
                print output
```

Output (example `'be your self'` from `L2`):

```
('b', 'b', 'be your self')
('b', 'e', 'be your self')
('b', 'y', 'be your self')
('e', 'b', 'be your self')
('e', 'e', 'be your self')
('e', 'y', 'be your self')
('y', 'b', 'be your self')
('y', 'e', 'be your self')
('y', 'y', 'be your self')
```

The output shows what I want, but in order visualize data, I need also to return the times `L1[j]`concurs with `L1[i]`.

For example:

```
  b e y
b 1 1 1
e 1 2 1
y 1 1 1
```

Should I use `pandas` or `numpy` in order to return this result?

I found this question about co-occurrence matrix but I didn't find and specific answer. [efficient algorithm for finding co occurrence matrix of phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982746/efficient-algorithm-for-finding-co-occurrence-matrix-of-phrases)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use a dictionary instead? `{'bb': 1, 'be': 1, ... etc}`

Comment: I'm confused, what do the counts in your matrix output correspond to? It doesn't matter that there are two e's in "be your self"? Do you want all of counts to be in a single collection, or do you want a collection for each phrase?

Comment: It matters, sorry. I just edited. I want a collection for each phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `itertools.product`. This should time significantly better than the accepted solution (if that's an issue).

```
from itertools import product
from operator import mul

L1 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 't', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
L2 = ['the onion', 'be your self', 'great zoo', 'x men', 'corn day']

phrase_map = {}

for phrase in L2:
    word_count = {word: phrase.count(word) for word in L1 if word in phrase}

    occurrence_map = {}
    for perm in product(word_count, repeat=2):
        occurrence_map[perm] = reduce(mul, (word_count[key] for key in perm), 1)

    phrase_map[phrase] = occurrence_map
```

From my timings, this is 2-4 times faster in Python 3 (there's probably less of an improvement in Python 2). Also, in Python 3, you need to import `reduce` from `functools`.

**Edit:** Note that, while this implementation is relatively simple, there are obvious inefficiencies. For example, we know that the corresponding output will be symmetric and this solution does not exploit that. Using `combinations_with_replacements` instead of `product` will generate only the entries in the upper triangular part of your output matrix. Thus, we can improve of the above solution by doing:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

L1 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 't', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
L2 = ['the onion', 'be your self', 'great zoo', 'x men', 'corn day']

phrase_map = {}

for phrase in L2:
    word_count = {word: phrase.count(word) for word in L1 if word in phrase}

    occurrence_map = {}
    for x, y in combinations_with_replacement(word_count, 2):
        occurrence_map[(x,y)] = occurrence_map[(y,x)] = \
            word_count[x] * word_count[y]

    phrase_map[phrase] = occurrence_map

return phrase_map
```

As expected, this version takes half as long as the previous version. Note that this version relies on restricting yourself to pairs of two elements while the previous version did not.

Note that around 15-20% of the running time can be cut out if the line

```
 occurrence_map[(x,y)] = occurrence_map[(y,x)] = ...
```

is changed to

```
occurrence_map[(x,y)] = ...
```

but this may be less-than-ideal depending on how you are using this mapping in the future.

Comment: very nice solution

Comment: Thank you, Jared. Great solution. It works great in python 2.7.

Comment: @estebanpdl If you're trying to further cut down on the time, I've improved the solution; see the code after the **Edit**.

Answer (score 1):

Ok why don't you try this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

L1 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 't', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
L2 = ['the onion', 'be your self', 'great zoo', 'x men', 'corn day', 'yes be your self']

d = dict.fromkeys(L2)

for s, phrase in enumerate(L2):
    d[phrase] = defaultdict(int)
    for letter1 in phrase:
        for letter2 in phrase:
            if letter1 in L1 and letter2 in L1:
                output = letter1, letter2, phrase
                print output
                key = (letter1, letter2)
                d[phrase][key] += 1

print d
```

To catch the duplicate values you need to traverse the phrase, *not* the list L1, and then see if each letter in the phrase is in L1 (in other words swap the `in` expression around).

Output:

```
{
'x men': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('e', 'e'): 1, ('e', 'x'): 1, ('x', 'x'): 1, ('x', 'e'): 1}),
'great zoo': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('t', 't'): 1, ('t', 'z'): 1, ('e', 'e'): 1, ('e', 'z'): 1, ('t', 'e'): 1, ('z', 'e'): 1, ('z', 't'): 1, ('e', 't'): 1, ('z', 'z'): 1}),
'the onion': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('e', 't'): 1, ('t', 'e'): 1, ('e', 'e'): 1, ('t', 't'): 1}),
'be your self': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('b', 'y'): 1, ('b', 'b'): 1, ('e', 'e'): 4, ('y', 'e'): 2, ('y', 'b'): 1, ('y', 'y'): 1, ('e', 'b'): 2, ('e', 'y'): 2, ('b', 'e'): 2}),
'corn day': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('d', 'd'): 1, ('y', 'd'): 1, ('d', 'y'): 1, ('y', 'y'): 1, ('y', 'c'): 1, ('c', 'c'): 1, ('c', 'y'): 1, ('c', 'd'): 1, ('d', 'c'): 1}),
'yes be your self': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('b', 'y'): 2, ('b', 'b'): 1, ('e', 'e'): 9, ('y', 'e'): 6, ('y', 'b'): 2, ('y', 'y'): 4, ('e', 'b'): 3, ('e', 'y'): 6, ('b', 'e'): 3})
}
```

Comment: Excellent. However, if phrase contains an item from `L1` twice, is it possible to get, for example: `'b'` concurs with `'y'` in `'yes be your self'`, so the value of `y` is 2.

Comment: Ok I've edited the answer.  Are those the expected values?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you so much, K. Menyah. This solution wil help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
import collections, numpy
    tokens=['He','is','not','lazy','intelligent','smart']
    j=0
    a=np.zeros((len(tokens),len(tokens)))
    for pos,token in enumerate(tokens):
        j+=pos+1
        for token1 in tokens[pos+1:]:
            count = 0
            for sentence in [['He','is','not','lazy','He','is','intelligent','He','is','smart'] ]:
                    occurrences1 = [i for i,e in enumerate(sentence) if e == token1]
                    #print(token1,occurrences1)
                    occurrences2 = [i for i,e in enumerate(sentence) if e == token]
                    #print(token,occurrences2)
                    new1= np.repeat(occurrences1,len(occurrences2))
                    new2= np.asarray(occurrences2*len(occurrences1))
                    final_new= np.subtract(new1,new2)
                    final_abs_diff = np.absolute(final_new)
                    final_counts = collections.Counter(final_abs_diff)
                    count_1=final_counts[1]
                    count_2=final_counts[2]
                    count_0=final_counts[0]
                    count=count_1+count_2+count_0
            a[pos][j]=count
            #print(token,' ',pos,' ',token1,' ',j,' ',count)
            j+=1
        j=0

    final_mat = a.T+a
    print(final_mat)
```

Output is :

```
[[0. 4. 2. 1. 2. 1.]
 [4. 0. 1. 2. 2. 1.]
 [2. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 2. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```